# how to set dynamic header in spring remoting

Tags: java, spring-remoting

We need to call a Bean class using spring remoting and also set dynamic header in the call. We can set custom `HttpInvokerRequestExecutor` in the  `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` and add header but how to set dynamic header generated on the fly for the request?

```
In the Config class, declaring the HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean
@Bean
@Qualifier("service")
public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker() {
    HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    invoker.setServiceUrl(url);
    invoker.setServiceInterface(Service.class);
    return invoker;
}

In the invoker class
@Autowired
Service service;

public void invoke(Bean bean) {
    service.process(bean);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a long time that I used spring remoting but as far as I remember I found a solution to this by subclassing of SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor which is default when you do not set any custom request executor to HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.

IMHO you can write a custom request executor which you can set custom header values and a simple helper component which sets the dynamically provided values to the executor before the next request.

CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor:

```
public class CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor extends SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor {

private Map<String, String> headers;

public void setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
}

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, int contentLength) throws IOException {
    super.prepareConnection(connection, contentLength);

    if (headers != null) {
        // adding our custom headers
        for (String headerName : headers.keySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(headerName, headers.get(headerName));
        }
        // do not want to persist headers for another request!
        headers.clear();
    }
}
}
```

CustomRemoteExecutor:

```
@Component
public class CustomRemoteExecutor {

@Autowired
private HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean factoryBean;

/*
 * May be you should need a synchronized modifier here if there is possibility
 * of multiple threads access here at the same time
 */
public void executeInTemplate(Map<String, String> headers, Runnable task) {
    CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor executor = (CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor) factoryBean.getHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
    executor.setHeaders(headers);
    task.run();
}
```

}

And then you can use it by below:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("service")
public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker() {
    HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    invoker.setServiceUrl(testUrl);
    invoker.setServiceInterface(Service.class);
    // set our custom request executor
    CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor executor = new CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
    invoker.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(executor);

    return invoker;
}

@Autowired
CustomRemoteExecutor executor;

@Autowired
Service service;

public void invoke(Bean bean) {

    // when you need custom headers
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("CUSTOM_HEADER", "CUSTOM_VALUE");
    headers.put("CUSTOM_HEADER2", "CUSTOM_VALUE2");
    executor.executeInTemplate(headers, () -> service.process(bean));

}
```

There is one drawback here as I also stated in comments, if you execute your proxy service client in a multithreaded environment (server to server requests may be) you should consider to make `executeInTemplate` method `synchronized`

An addition to my answer if your service method needs to return some object then you can add another helper method to `CustomRemoteExecutor` and use it when you need to return something. The method can have the same name here so it can overload the former one which is much better I think.

```
public <T> T executeInTemplate(Map<String, String> headers, Callable<T> task) {
    CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor executor = (CustomHttpInvokerRequestExecutor) factoryBean.getHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
    executor.setHeaders(headers);

    try {
        return task.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // it is better to log this exception by your preferred logger (log4j, logback
        // etc.)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And again you can use like below:

```
@Autowired
CustomRemoteExecutor executor;

@Autowired
ISampleService service;

public void invoke(Bean bean) {

    // when you need custom headers
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("CUSTOM_HEADER", "CUSTOM_VALUE");
    headers.put("CUSTOM_HEADER2", "CUSTOM_VALUE2");

    // assume that service.returnSomething() method returns String
    String value = executor.executeInTemplate(headers, () -> service.returnSomething(bean));

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Yavuz. will it work if invoke method has value to be returned?

Comment: No, if you need to return something you should write another helper method which takes argument as Callable instead of Runnable. I think it should be possible and may be better by using generics. I am going to update the answer to show a sample in a while...

Comment: I updated my answer to cover your last question, hope it helps